# Archiving application produces blurry icon on organizer screen

Tags: ios, archiving

I have specified retina and non retina images and verified I put them in the right location in  Xcode. After archiving the app, the icon appears blurry as shown in attachment.

What can I do to fix this?

[image]

Plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>app_icon_57.png</string>
                <string>app_icon_114.png</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.gannett.democratandchronicle.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>MainStoryboard</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Comment: I've never been able to correctly show that icon. I'm interested to see if there's a way to do that.

Comment: I have seen that too, I think it is just because it blows up the icon there.  I have not seen it affect the actual look of the icon once I move it to a device though.  You also upload a different artwork for the App Store large icon too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only blurry in the organizer. 
It has no effect on the Icon on the users device or on the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in xcode - I have submitted a radar ([openradar link](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2286402)) describing it to Apple.

As pre described above, it does not affect the created .ipa on iOS. If the problem bugs you enough, a work-around is to define the @2x version of your icon BEFORE the 1x version in your info.plist icon files array.

Comment: It bugged me enough, and Ryan's suggestion did fix it for me.